# Find row from database depending on the value which is nearest to the given value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find table row from database depending on the value which is nearest to the given value.

I have following data

```
Id  Rate         Fat
1   10           8.00
2   20           8.10
3   30           8.20
4   40           8.30
5   50           8.34
6   60           8.40
7   50           8.36
```

suppose user want to find using the Fat

For 8.0 it should return

```
Id  Rate         Fat
1   10           8.00
```

For 8.06 it should return

```
Id  Rate         Fat
2   20           8.10
```

For 8.35 it should return 8.34 instead 8.36 (though difference is same it should give preference to lower value if difference is same)

```
Id  Rate         Fat
5   60           8.34
```

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server you could do this

```
select top 1 *
from T
order by abs(Fat - 8.35), Fat
```

I **guess** that syntax for MySQL is

```
select *
from T
order by abs(Fat - 8.35), Fat
limit 1
```

Comment: @Johan – Thanks for the confirmation.